# Programmatically Perform Child View Click in ExpandableListView

Tags: java, android, testing, expandablelistview

I have an ExpandableListView implementation in my application and I am writing unit tests for it. I'm wondering how I can programmatically perform a click on the child view of an expandable header?

This is NOT a question about how to attach onChildClickListener() to the view. I've found many questions regarding that topic, but I already have that implemented and need to test the functionality of that code when the child view is clicked. I know that I can use the performClick() method to click on the header view to expand/collapse the contents, but I need to perform a click on the sublist of a header.

Answer (score 2):

You can try with:

```
listView.setSelection(position);
```

but you have to consider this:

> If in touch mode, the item will not be selected but it will still be
>   positioned appropriately. If the specified selection position is less
>   than 0, then the item at position 0 will be selected.

For more information you can visit the [doc page](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#setSelection(int)).

I hope it helps.

**Edit**

As @RyanM appointed, *setSelection* just change the selection, but it doesn't perform the "click" action. You can perform the action through the function:

```
listView.performItemClick(goalListView, itemPosition, itemId);
```

You can find this function in the class [AdapterView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.html#performItemClick(android.view.View,%20int,%20long)).

Sorry for the previous mistake to your answer.

Comment: 1.) That will only set the selection, not perform a click.
2.) If the 'listView' is the sub-ListView of an expandable header, how did you get it?
3.) If the 'listView' is the ExpandableListView, that will only set the header item at 'position' to be selected, not clicked.

Comment: I assume that the 'goalListView' attribute is the sublist that I want to perform the click upon. How do I get that list subview from the ExpandableListView that I have implemented? (Number 2 in my original comment) As a refresher... An expandable list view is a list of header items, each holding a sub-listview that contains its child views. It is that list of child views that I am trying to perform click events upon.

Comment: Yes, the "goalListView" is the sublist. About the refresher, I'm not sure, check it.

Comment: That's the basis of my question... I don't know how to get that sublist to perform clicks on it.

Comment: Without your code it is tough to guess how to do it.